# Highcharts Angular: Chart not showing some points?

Tags: angular, graph, highcharts, frontend

I am generating a highcharts plot or work. It shows a line plot but some points are not visible but only exist when hovered over them [As apparent in this picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBC2f.png)

I am trying to find what the problem is but don't seem to find it in the highcharts doc. I am generating the chart in as a separate TS component and then putting it in the markup using tags. This is done using a drawcharts method which gets called when the page loads, this method is as follows:

```
  draw(){
    let self = this;

    this.chart =  Highcharts.stockChart(this.id, {
        title: {
            text: self.title,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 0,
            style: {
                'font-size': '16px',
                'font-weight': 'bold'
            }
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            spacingTop: 20,
            animation: false,
            events: {
                redraw(){
                    self.redrawEvent(self,['legend','fullScreen']);
                }
            }
        },
        navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
        },
        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            },
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function(e){
                    self.updatedData.emit(e);
                    self.xRanges = [e.min, e.max];
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        self.updateLegends.call(self);
                    }, 100)
                    // self.updateLegends.call(self);
                }
            },
            min: new Date(this.from).getTime(),
            max: new Date(this.to).getTime()
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: this.yAxisTitle,
              margin: 60
            },
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                    self.yRanges = [e.min, e.max];
                    if (self.dataEmpty) {
                        self.updateLegends.call(self, self.chart.legend.allItems);
                    }
                }
            },
            labels: {
                // opposite: true,
                formatter: function(){
                    return self.type == 'tt' ?
                        secondFormatter(this.value, true).replace(' min', '')
                        : this.value + '';
                },
                x: 40,
            },
            floor: 0
        },
        tooltip:{
            split: this.fromComparison,
            shared: !this.fromComparison,
            useHTML: true,
            animation: false,
            formatter: function() {
                switch (self.type){
                    case 'tt': return self.TTFormatter(this);
                    case 'speed': return self.SpeedFormatter(this);
                    case 'heartbeat': return self.HeartbeatFormatter(this);
                    case 'count': return self.countFormatter(this);
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            margin: 5,
            padding: 5,
            x: 50,
            y: -10,
            labelFormatter: function () {
                return this.name;
            },
            useHTML:true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                // fillColor: {
                //     linearGradient: {
                //         x1: 0,
                //         y1: 0,
                //         x2: 0,
                //         y2: 1
                //     },
                //     stops: [
                //         [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                //         [1, new Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                //     ]
                // },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },
        stockTools: {
            gui: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
                // bug reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14173
                buttons: ['FullScreen','Legends','separator','measure'],
                enabled: true,
                definitions: {
                      'FullScreen': {
                          className: 'highcharts-custom-full-screen'+self.id,
                          symbol: 'fullscreen.svg'
                      },
                      Legends: {
                          className: 'highcharts-display-legends'+self.id,
                          symbol: 'horizontal-line.svg'
                      },
                },
            }))
        },
    });

    this.updateDotsSeries();
    this.updateLineSeries();

    this.addListeners(['legend','fullScreen'],self.id)

    this.chart.redraw();


    this.updateLegends();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Arunasva Bhuyan, Could you provide me with a sample of your data?

Comment: @ppotaczek non Idk how

Comment: You can create a minimal live reproduction of the problem. You can start from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line